# Use a View Controller as a camera overlay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that loads the camera and overlays buttons for fire, reload, and back, as well as a png that animates when the fire and reload buttons are tapped. How would I load the View Controller, which has a .xib with the buttons and image, as an overlay when the camera view loads?

I have the camera view loading when a button on the main screen is tapped, which used to open another View with the buttons and gun image.

Below is what I have done so far, which is loading the camera. I have a separate View Controller named PlayViewController, with an xib for the interface:

```
-(IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender {


UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

PlayViewController* overlay = [[PlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayViewController" bundle:nil];
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
[picker setDelegate:overlay];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}
This is in the PlayViewController.m: `code`

```
   #import "PlayViewController.h"
   #import "SoundViewController.h"

@interface PlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayViewControlleriPad...
```

`

PlayViewController.h:

```
@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{

two array declarations...

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *reloadButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *fireButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ammoField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *type;

@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create your view controller and xib as usual, then add this to your code:

```
YourOverlay* overlay = [[YourOverlay alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourOverlayView" bundle:nil];
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
[picker setDelegate:overlay];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The overlay must implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Comment: Doing this gives me an error for the line [picker] setDelegate:overlay]; as follows: 'Sending 'PlayViewControlleriPad *_strong to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>'

Comment: the overlay must implement those protocols. @interface YourOverlay : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

Comment: I have implemented those protocols, and it still gives me the warning. Unless the order of the two matters?

Comment: The order does not matter, update your question including a bit of code of the overlay controller, maybe the issue is elsewhere

Comment: You need to implement the two delegates in you .h file, if you declare them in the private category, in your .m file, when you set the delegate from the other viewcontroller you get the warning that you mentioned. So @interface PlayViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>  in your .h file

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it worked the first couple of times and is now freezing before the camera view loads. It does the shutter animation, then before the shutter opens to the camera it freezes.

Comment: What does the debugger say? Did you implement the required methods of the delagate protocol?

Comment: Just (lldb). I have in the .h file for PlayViewController the two delegate methods, <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> and <UINavigationControllerDelegate>. Does the SoundViewController (original view, linking to the camera view + overlay) need any delegates methods?

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint tab in the left panel of xcode, click + to add a new breakpoint and add the generic exception breakpoint. Then run again your app, it should breakpoint where the exception is raised. If it keeps just showing the lldb console, press the continue button on the lldb console toolbar, until a log message is shown.

Comment: OK, I did that, it's stopping at the line: picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;

Comment: bad_access? Are you using ARC? Make sure to maintain a strong reference to your UIImagePickerController (using a strong property or the __strong keyword in the ivar declaration)

Comment: I figured out a different method, using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Thanks for all your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
picker.cameraOverlayView = someViewController.view;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is giving me an error: 'Property 'view' not found on object of type 'PlayViewController'. Is there anything I need to add to the PlayViewController?

Comment: @DaleTownsend are you sure your PlayViewController really is a view controller?

Comment: It should be, it has a .m, .h, and an xib for the interface. In the .h file it has @interface PlayViewController : UIViewController after the #import statement.

Comment: @DaleTownsend have you #imported the header file in the implementation file in which you create the image picker?

Comment: @DaleTownsend now that's strange

Comment: Do I need an @property called 'view' in the PlayViewController file?

Comment: OK, I'm not sure then. I've updated the question with more of the code. This is the last thing I need to do for my app, so I really need a solution.