# add gallery option while picking image from camera in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

i want to add camera feature in my app but the default camera view doesn't have the option to select image from the gallery and i am doing this because i don't want to make alert view for the user to select image picker type, i.e., camera or photo gallery. how to implement this??

```
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

   imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
   imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

   imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
   imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
```

Comment: use [AVCaptureSession Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: try this: 1. [Overlaying the iPhone camera without blocking its controls](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/overlaying-the-iphone-camera-without-blocking-its-controls/) 2. https://github.com/jj0b/OverlayViewTester 3. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225593/use-a-view-controller-as-a-camera-overlay 5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156417/how-do-you-create-a-custom-camera-view-instead-of-uiimagepickerviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
```

Comment: Please stop bugging people to look at your answers in your comments. They already are notified when you leave an answer, so these comments are being flagged as noise.